# Trying to save JSON data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but the following code below isn't saving to my database. I'm using rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.4.1. I have no controller or views and using Mysql if that's of any help.

**Model**

```
class Agent < ApplicationRecord

  json = JSON.parse('{"Agents":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","id":"57fa5f47-8851-11e7-b391-02cbcf8dd991"},{"firstName":"Alice","lastName":"Thompson","id":"77eccb07-101d-11e7-83be-02e5025d7d75"}]}')

  json['Agents'].each do |data|
    Agent.create(
    id: data['id'],
    first_name: data['firstName'],
    last_name: data['lastName']
  )
  end

end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "agents", id: :string, limit: 36, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
  end
```

Comment: Any validations in your model?. Try to assign the `Agent.create()` to a variable as `agent = Agent.create()` and try printing the errors `agent.errors` to check if any validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

As Gokul M pointed out, `firstName` and `lastName` need to be snake-cased to match your schema.  However, your code still will not work, because `:id` is a protected attribute in ActiveRecord models.  Meaning that it can’t be mass-assigned.  You can however assign it normally. i.e `model.id=foo`

So you could try something like

```
json['Agents'].each do |data|
  agent = Agent.new
  agent.id = data['id']
  agent.first_name = data['firstName']
  agent.last_name = data['lastName']
  agent.save
end
```

Though, I haven’t tested this code.

Comment: Thanks Outlaw. No luck with the above. I've even stripped back to trying only first_name and still no luck.

Comment: Are any ids coming from the json longer than 36 characters?

Comment: No. They a UUID's at 36 characters.

Comment: Do you have any custom code in the Agent model? If so, perhaps you could add it above and I’d be happy to look it over.  Other than that, I’m not sure.

Comment: No. All that I have in the model is what's above. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: I hadn’t realized that was your model until you said that just now.  I would advise against executing any code inside your class definition.  Because it will get run every time your application starts up

Comment: If what you are trying to do is seed the database with records, then use db/seed.rb for that.

Comment: So place the above code in my seeds.rb? I guess what I'm trying to achieve is to store the JSON in a table just to update in the background every day (I haven't gotten that far yet).

Comment: Yes.  db/seed.rb is run at the end of database setup.  It will only ever need to be run once for a particular database.

Comment: Still no luck. Driving me bonkers!